# Running my own company along with a job in another company, how to communicate this to co-founder?

Tags: software-industry, communication, job-change

Me and my friend are running a small IT firm. There are no other employees, just the two of us. Business is not so bad, but we cannot live with just the income from this business.

I want to look for a good job in a reputed company without ending our own business, so that we can continue to run our business while having a secure income. I want to encourage my partner to do the same.

My partner is very motivated to run the company, and I am worried that he may not react well if I bring up the idea of finding stable jobs. How can I bring this up without destroying the business or my relationship with the co-founder?

Comment: Hi Joby, welcome to the Workplace SE. I edited this a bit to put the focus on what I think your question is. As a Q&A site, we're not a forum for advice, so it's important the question is clear. Please feel free to build upon these [edit]s to further clarify/put in your own words. Also, check out our [about] page, which gives new users a nice overview of how our site works. Good luck!

Comment: Hey @lorenzo, great comment! Just so you know, you can add magic links using things like `[about]` and `[edit]` to create links quickly and easily (you can also use `[help]` and variations like `[help/on-topic]` or `[help/dont-ask]`). Thanks again for helping out with comments!

Comment: Hey Joby, welcome to [workplace.se]! I made an [edit] to focus your question and make it match the guidelines in our [help/on-topic]. Since we are not a great format for getting personal career advice or telling you what to do, I focused your question on solving the problem of how to bring it up without having a negative impact on your business. Please feel free to [edit] your question again if you think I missed the point and you can improve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much @jmac and lorenzog. This helping mentality makes this community a big success!

Comment: Thank **you** @lorenzo, the community is what makes people like Joby find us such a great resource. Helpful comments and edits improve our content and add value to the site long-term. If you are looking for more ways to help, feel free to drop by [chat] where like-minded souls tend to congregate. Thanks again to both of you for improving this question!

Comment: A business is a full time adventure.  The purpose of starting your own business is to make money.  Your job is to GROW the business, not find other work while your partner tries to grow it all alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship and the personality of your partner are going to determine "how" to ask him about this, so I don't think I can give you any help there other than be open and honest

If I were a serious about a business and a partner was considering some other "distraction", I would want to know what he will do if we notice a conflict. To address this you need to A) establish a set of guidelines on the level of your participation you're going to maintain. B) Get some level of assurance you'll quit the job if it doesn't work out.

You may not be able to make this commitment or convince him otherwise. The only solution in this case is to break the partnership. Your partner may be willing to settle for less (Doesn't sound like it). Find out what his biggest concerns and fears are and make an effort to address them. There are no guarantees in life, but there are ways to cut risks.